# WPF Catch DragOver on whole window, but allow drop only on certain area

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I am trying to show an overlay in my app when the user drags files over.[image]
I already can catch dragover on the whole window and on the drop area. Dragging over the window already enables the overlay, but how can I block the drop on the app window and allow on the drop area?
My code so far:

```
    <Window DragOver="EnableDropOverlay" DragLeave="DragLeaveWindow" .../>
    private void EnableDropOverlay()
    {
        DropOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void DragLeaveWindow()
    {
        DropOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    <DropArea DragOver="DragOver_area" ../>
    private void DragOver_area(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Link;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Handle the `Drop` event only for `DropOverlay`?

Comment: Yes, I want for drop to only be possible on DropOverlay, but DropOverlay should trigger when the user drags files over the app.

Comment: Yes? So what's the problem with my suggestion then?

Comment: The problem is that when I drag over the app window it allows me to drop files there, but I want the drop to only be allowed on the overlay

Comment: It depends what "allow" means. If you drop them there and don't handle the drop, nothing will happen. Isn't this what you want?